# Compute the coefficients of Fourier for an arbitrary period $T$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let be $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an absolutely integrable function, periodic with fundamental period $2L$ and $T$ an arbitrary period (not necessarily the fundamental period) of $f$. Show that
>
> $$a_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(x) \cos \left( \frac{2n \pi x}{T} \right) dx, \ b_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(x) \sin \left( \frac{2n \pi x}{T} \right) dx.$$

I would like to receive a hint, because I don't have idea how to start in order to proof this. Thanks in advance!

> $\textbf{EDIT}$
>
> The definition of Fourier Coefficients for a function periodic with period $2L$:
>
> $$a_n = \frac{1}{L} \int^L_{-L} f(x) \cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx, \ b_n = \frac{1}{L} \int^L_{-L} f(x) \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx.$$

Comment: Your question is unclear. But $T = k 2L$ for some integer $k$. What you wrote is the definition of the Fourier series coefficients of an arbitrary $T$-periodic function $f$. Can you relate them to the Fourier coefficients of $f$ seen as a $2L$-periodic function ?

Comment: @reuns, I edited my post with the definition of Fourier coefficients that I'm using.

Comment: You didn't get the point. $f$ is $2L$ periodic **and** $T$ periodic. Your two $a_n$ are not the same.